# No rule to make target error output while building C project using GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to build a dummy C project using GNU Make. I use the following rules to build the object files from the c files and the output from the object files :

```
AT := @

#Initial tools to get the absolute paths.
TOOLSDIR                    := ./tools/bin
SHELL                       := $(TOOLSDIR)/sh
CYGPATH                     := $(TOOLSDIR)/cygpath

# Defining used tools
TOOLSDIR                    := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)")
SCRIPTDIR                   := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(SCRIPTDIR)")
LIBDIR                      := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(LIBDIR)")

#Defining Env Variable responsible for Removing non-ansi characters in error output
LC_ALL=C

SHELL                       := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(SHELL)")
CYGPATH                     := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(CYGPATH)")
TEST                        := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)/test")
RM                          := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)/rm") -f
PERL                        := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)/perl")
FIND                        := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)/find")
MKDIR                       := $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$(TOOLSDIR)/mkdir")

PERL5LIB                    := $(LIBDIR)/perl5/site_perl/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads;$(LIBDIR)/perl5/site_perl/5.14;$(LIBDIR)/perl5/5.14/x86_64-cygwin-threads;$(LIBDIR)/perl5/5.14

# Defining perl script to convert dependencies genereted by the compiler to unix path
FIXDEPS_SCRIPT              := "$(SCRIPTDIR)/fixdeps.pl"
ZAPEXEC_SCRIPT              := "$(SCRIPTDIR)/ZAP_Command.pl"

DEPFIX                      := $(PERL) $(FIXDEPS_SCRIPT)
ZAPEXE                      := $(PERL) $(ZAPEXEC_SCRIPT)
CREATE_IAR_PROJ             := $(PERL) $(IARWKSP_SCRIPT)

COMP_DIR                    :=C:\ghs\comp_201355

OBJDIR                      :=.

CC                          := "$(COMP_DIR)/ccrh850.exe"
AS                          := "$(COMP_DIR)/ccrh850.exe"
LD                          := "$(COMP_DIR)/ccrh580.exe"
GSREC                       := "$(COMP_DIR)/gsrec.exe"
GMEM                        := "$(COMP_DIR)/gmemfile.exe"

CEXT                        :=c
CCEXT                       :=C
ASMEXTC                     := S
ASMEXTS                     := s
ASMEXT                      := 850
ASMEXT_DEFAULT              := asm
DBGEXT                      := dla
DBGEXT_DEFAULT              := dnm 
OBJEXT                      := o
EXEEXT                      := elf
LSTEXT                      := lst
DEPEXT                      := dd
INCOPT                      := -I

EXEMAP                      := ./exe/PROJECT_NAME.map

CFLAGS                      :=-c -G  -Onone  -no_callt -sda=all -large_sda -reserve_r2 -Wundef --short_enum -dual_debug \
-delete -preprocess_assembly_files --no_wrap_diagnostics -registermode=32 -keeptempfiles -prepare_dispose -ansi  \
-full_debug_info -noobj -Wimplicit-int -Wshadow -Wtrigraphs -inline_prologue -DOS_MEMMAP=0 -DOS_MULTICORE=OS_SINGLE \
-DOS_USE_CLZ_QUEUE_ALGORITHM=1 -DOS_DEVELOPMENT_SANITY_CHECKS=0 -DOS_KERNEL_TYPE=OS_FUNCTION_CALL -DOS_USE_TRACE=0 -MD \
-DAUTOSAR_USED -DRENESAS  -DF1K   -DR7F701583xAFP --long_long  -cpu=rh850 -DTS_ARCH_FAMILY=TS_RH850 \
-DTS_ARCH_DERIVATE=TS_RH850F1L -DRH850F1L=1 -DOS_CPU=OS_RH850F1L -DOS_TOOL=OS_ghs -DOS_ARCH=OS_RH850

VPATH                       :=./ ./obj ./src ./exe

INCLUDES                    :=-I"./" -I"./obj" -I"./src" -I"./exe"
OBJECTS                     :=./obj/main.o

.PHONY: all release debug

EXEC                        := ./exe/PROJECT_NAME.hex
EXEOUT                      := ./exe/PROJECT_NAME.out
    
all: debug release

release: $(EXEC)
debug: release

$(EXEC): $(EXEOUT)
    @echo '************************************'
    @echo 'Using GSREC to Convert .out to .hex'
    $(AT)$(GSREC) -o$(EXEC) $(EXEOUT)
    @echo 'Generation Done'
    @echo '************************************'

$(EXEOUT): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo '************************************'
    @echo 'Building .out file'
    @echo $(EXEOUT)
    $(AT)$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXEOUT) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo '************************************'

$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): %.$(CEXT)
    @echo 'Compiling: $<'
    $(AT)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -filetype.c $(shell $(CYGPATH) -am "$<")  -o $@
```

The output when I execute the target `all` is as follows :

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by 'exe/PROJECT_NAME.out'.  Stop.
```

The main.c source file has the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "alpha.c"

void second(void);
int main()
{
  printf("Second module, I send you greetings!n");
  second();
  return 0;
}
```

The alpha.c source file has the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
void second(void)
{
  puts("Glad to be here!");
}
```

Where `$(OBJECTS)` is the relative path of all the object files that are supposed to be generated and `$(EXEC)` and `$(EXEOUT)` are the outputs. The `VPATH` contains relative paths. All the needed prerequisites (.c and.h files) can be found among the paths in `VPATH` and in `INCLUDES` in the compilation command. That is the exact code I use to build this dummy project which contains only two .c files ***main.c*** and ***alpha.c*** and ***main.c*** uses ***alpha.c***. When the source files are in the same folder as the makefile this dummy project builds, but when I put the source files in the ***src*** folder and create a ***obj*** folder for the object files to be generated in and an ***exe*** folder for the final output to be generated in previously mentioned error appears.  What could be the reason for the previously mentioned error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at our [intro section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with special attention to the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code you have posted is not sufficient for us to reproduce the error; there are pieces missing, like `$(RELATIVE_OBJDIR)` and `$(CEXT)`, so the flaw could be anywhere. If you reduce this makefile down to a minimal complete example, the source of the error will probably become obvious along the way, and if not then you will have a minimal complete example you can show us.

Answer (score 1):

@Beta is right that it's generally a bad idea to dump a huge makefile into StackOverflow and ask someone to fix it.  You should instead try to reduce the problem as much as possible.

However in this case, your problem is here:

```
OBJDIR                      :=.

OBJECTS                     :=./obj/main.o

$(EXEOUT): $(OBJECTS)
    ...
$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OBJEXT): %.$(CEXT)
    ...
```

So after all the variables have been expanded, you get these rules:

```
./exe/PROJECT_NAME.out: ./obj/main.o
    ...
./%.o: %.c
    ...
```

Well, when make tries to match the pattern `./%.o` with the target to be built `./obj/main.o`, the stem `%` will match `obj/main`.  Then it will try to find `%.c` which resolves to `obj/main.c`, which doesn't exist.

You should be using the `OBJDIR` variable in your `OBJECTS` variable assignment, like:

```
OBJECTS                     :=$(OBJDIR)/main.o
```

then it will work.